# htaccess syntax and rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to create a Friendly URL`s.

I have a movie database, every movie has it
**id**, **title**, **year** and **slug** ('title-year').

On the home page, movies are linked like -> *example.com/movie.php?id=28*

What rules do I have to write to make the address look like my **slug**? 
-> *example.com/title-year*

I was looking for solutions but I do not understand htaccess syntax.

Comment: About video URL, htaccess rewrite is not enough because the origin url includes only video id data nd you friendly url requires slug data. First you have to rewrite you movie.php page to take slug as parameter instead id

Comment: @BenjaminCaure I've already done that

Comment: If you did actually search for this: try with more descriptive question titles. There's a bazillion similar questions on SO already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming movie.php takes slug as parameter instead of id.

```
example.com/movie.php?slug=pulpfiction-1994
```

Here is .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   "^/movie/(.+)"  "http://example.com/movie.php?slug=$1"  [R,L]
```

This should rewrite url

```
http://example.com/movie/pulpfiction-1994
```

as

```
http://example.com/movie.php?slug=pulpfiction-1994
```